# Can't get output from Popen when run through IIS

Tags: python, iis, cgi, subprocess

I'm using the following python script on Windows Server 2008:

```
import cgitb
import subprocess

cgitb.enable()
print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

cmd = "git tag"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
git_output = process.communicate()[0]
print "git output = %s" % git_output
```

There are, in fact, some git tags. Running this script through the shell works perfectly. However, when run through IIS (7), the output seems to be empty.

I've tried directing the Popen output to a file instead of PIPE. Again, worked when running from the command line, didn't work when running through IIS.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Following @Wooble's advice, I removed the [0] from the call to communicate to see git errors, and indeed found the enigmatic error "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Of course git is installed on the system, and as I said the script works when run directly through the command line.

To no avail, I tried:

1. Setting the command to use the full path of the git executable
2. Adding the full path of the git executable directory to python's sys.path
3. Copying the actual git executable to the working directory - this removed the "git not recognized" error but still yielded an empty result!

Please help!!

Comment: Is it at least printing "git output =" at the start of the page? Are you sure the script's working directory is what you think it is? Is there anything in your error logs?

Comment: Yes, it prints "git output =". I'm sure about the working directory, because when I directed the output to a file, the file was actually opened in the expected directory, but was empty (when run from the shell, it contained the expected output). Nothing in the logs, unless I'm not looking the correct place - I looked in C:\inetpub\logs (I'm very new to IIS).

Comment: Oh, right, you're capturing stderr so it wouldn't get to your logs. Try getting rid of the `[0]` on the next to last line so you can see the error output from git, if any.

Comment: Holy crap, "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." But... It works from the command line, why would this happen? Do I have to add git to some IIS path variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the path was partial when running from IIS (explanations welcome!), but adding this finally solved the problem:

```
git_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\"
os.environ["PATH"} += git_path + ';'
```